# SQL Left Join not including desired rows

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join

I'm trying to join 2 tables, where all data in the left table appears and only data that matches in the right table appears - should be a simple `LEFT JOIN`.  But I either get results where only data in both tables appear if they match, or some of the data in left table and a correct set of data that matches in the right table.

Here's the code:

```
SELECT 
    tblCalendar.dDate, tblCalendar.dDay, 
    tblDailyData.TradeableDate, tblDailyData.TradeableCode
FROM 
    tblCalendar 
LEFT JOIN 
    tblDailyData ON tblCalendar.[dDate] = tblDailyData.[TradeableDate]
WHERE 
    (((tblDailyData.TradeableCode) = "MSFT")) 
     OR (((tblDailyData.TradeableDate) IS NULL) 
         AND ((tblDailyData.TradeableCode) IS NULL))
ORDER BY 
    tblCalendar.dDate;
```

Correct output should be (see image):

- **all** `tblCalendar.dDate` and `tblCalendar.dDay` rows
- and **only** the rows where `tblDailyData.TradeableDate` and `tblDailyData.TradeableCode` correspond to the tblCalendar days.

I've been trying to figure this out for hours. I've tried ChatGPT, resources here, numerous online resources, and the query builder in MS Access. I suspect I'm doing something wrong with the `WHERE` and `ON` clauses, but I can't figure out what.

Appreciate any help the group could provide.

Comment: There is no image  in your post. Provide sample data as formatted text tables, not image. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support

Comment: I would try temporarily removing the `WHERE` clause, just to make sure you can see at least *some* of what you expect; you don't mention what you **do** see, and why it's wrong.

Comment: Build a query of tblDailyData that filters then join that query to tblCalendar.

Comment: `(((tblDailyData.TradeableCode) = "MSFT"))` on your `WHERE` literally turn your `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

Move the filtering to a subquery:

```sql
SELECT 
    tblDailyData.TradeableDate, 
    tblDailyData.TradeableCode
FROM 
    tblDailyData
WHERE 
    (tblDailyData.TradeableCode = "MSFT") 
        OR 
    (tblDailyData.TradeableCode IS NULL 
    AND 
    tblDailyData.TradeableDate IS NULL);
```

Save it as, say, `qryDailyData`.

Then run this query:

```sql
SELECT 
    tblCalendar.dDate, 
    tblCalendar.dDay, 
    qryDailyData.TradeableDate, 
    qryDailyData.TradeableCode
FROM 
    tblCalendar 
LEFT JOIN 
    qryDailyData ON tblCalendar.[dDate] = qryDailyData.[TradeableDate]
ORDER BY 
    tblCalendar.dDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the data, it's hard to determine the core issue. These two lines, would only join if you had a `NULL` in `tblCalendar.dDate`. A simple test in your query would be to do a `FULL OUTER JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN`.

```
     OR (((tblDailyData.TradeableDate) IS NULL) 
         AND ((tblDailyData.TradeableCode) IS NULL))
```

If it's necessary to get `NULL` `tblDailyData.TradeableDate`, you could handle it with a `RIGHT JOIN` to `tblCalendar` as a set, then `FULL OUTTER JOIN` from `tblCalendar` to that set.

```
WITH filteredDailyData AS(
SELECT
    tblDailyData.TradeableDate ,
    tblDailyData.TradeableCode
FROM tblDailyData
WHERE
    tblDailyData.TradeableCode = "MSFT"
    OR (tblDailyData.TradeableDate IS NULL 
        AND tblDailyData.TradeableCode IS NULL)
),
filteredCalendarDailyData AS(
SELECT
   tc.dDate,
   tc.dDay,
   fdr.TradeableDate,
   fdr.TradeableCode
FROM filteredDailyData AS fdr
RIGHT JOIN tblCalendar AS tc ON
   fdr.TradeableDate = fdr.dDate
),
fullCalendarFilteredDailyData AS(
SELECT
   c.dDate,
   c.dDay,
   fcdd.TradeableDate,
   fcdd.TradeableCode
FROM tblCalendar AS c
FULL OUTER JOIN filteredCalendarDailyData AS fcdd ON
   c.dDate = fcdd.dDate

)
SELECT * FROM fullCalendarFilteredDailyData
```

Comment: Access does not support WITH and FULL OUTER JOIN.